# Why is Sagepay notification using GET not POST?

Tags: opayo

I've implemented Sagepay (using C#/ASP.NET) as per the integration guide. It's not working as expected in that although all the payments go through my notification script isn't working.

The guide says:

*The Sage Pay servers send an HTTP or HTTPS POST to the NotificationURL script on your server to indicate the outcome of the transaction using ports 80 and 443. Please ensure you use these ports only as hard coding any other ports will generate errors. The transaction authorisation results are always POSTed to your NotificationURL.*

This is not what i'm seeing though, the notification url is being accessed by GET not POST, and so i'm unable to access any transaction infomation using:

```
IServerNotificationRequest serverNotificationRequest = new SagePayServerIntegration().GetServerNotificationRequest();
serverNotificationRequest.VendorTxCode // <- this is an empty string
```

Any help appreciated. Has anyone seen this behavour where it's using GET not POST?

Thanks

Comment: As a general comment from someone world-weary from dealing with payment providers, I recommend that you (a) never assume they will behave in any logical fashion, (b) never assume that they will not change from day to day without updating their documentation, (c) never assume they actually follow their own documentation. Stripe appears to be the least horrible in this respect.

Comment: This is happening to me too, I'm just getting a GET with no request vars.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because they were contacting the server on example.com/callback as I told them to and our apache config was redirecting them to www.example.com/callback, which they then accessed with GET.